# Phing - Passing a password from a shell script to svn

Tags: php, bash, svn, pear, phing

I don't want my Phing deployment script to echo entered passwords in clear text so I'm trying to create a shell script that reads the password without displaying the entered characters.

My script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -s -p "" password;
echo "$password"
```

(BTW: This solution is thanks to a comment posted by somebody on Phing's ticket tracker: https://www.phing.info/trac/ticket/885)

This works fine if I call it directly from the command line like so:

```
svn up --username myusername --password `/bin/bash /path/to/script/getpassword.sh`
```

It also works from within Phing if the password doesn't contain special characters. Strangely it leads to an svn authentication error if I enter my password which happens to contain a hash (#) sign. I cannot reproduce this behaviour from the command line like in the example above.

Here's the Phing part:

```
    <propertyprompt propertyname="svn.user" prompttext="Please tell me your svn username:"/>
    <echo>"Please tell me your svn password:[]</echo>
    <exec command="sh ${application.startdir}/path/to/script/getpassword.sh" outputProperty="svn.pass" />

    <svnupdate
       svnpath="/usr/bin/svn"
       username="${svn.user}"
       password="${svn.pass}"
       nocache="true"
       todir="${path-checkout}"/>
```

Has anybody got an idea what might be the cause of this issue? I skimmed through the sources in `PEAR/pear/php/phing/tasks/ext/svn` but didn't find anything suspicious.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using echo -n to not print the trailing newline character?